# Exclude table unit from the html string if there is selected phrase found

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I will try to explain the issue with an example.

Let's say I have big html string which includes following types of table units.

```
<table id="table-1">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 1}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 1 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-3">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 2}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-4">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 2 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need `PHP` function to exclude the complete table from the html string if it contains `{{Phrase 1}}` or `{{Phrase 2}}`.

Simply in above example I need to exclude `table-1` & `table-3` and the result string would be like bellow,

```
<table id="table-2">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 1 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-4">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 2 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the `preg_replace` function but it didn't work as I can just replace the selected text not whole unit.

Can anyone here help me to overcome this issue.

Sample code which I had so far and still trying to develop it.

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '{{Phrase 1}}';
$patterns[1] = '{{Phrase 2}}';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';

$string = '<table id="table-1">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 1}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 1 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-3">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 2}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-4">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 2 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: You said that you tried something. Show us the code.

Comment: Is the HTML always the same?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will add the code

Comment: @Andreas structure is same, but content can be change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is always the same, then you can do it in a simple regex:

```
// This regex matches the current structure, no matter what the number for the table id is 
// and either Phrase 1 or 2.
$regex = '/(<table id="table-[0-9]+">[\s]+<tbody>[\s]+<tr><td><p>\{\{Phrase (1|2)\}\}<\/p><\/td><\/tr>[\s]+<\/tbody>[\s]+<\/table>)/';

$html = '<table id="table-1">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 1}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 1 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-3">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 2}}</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-4">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><p>Sample text 2 goes here..</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

// Simply perform a replace with an empty string
$clean = preg_replace($regex, '', $html);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4QHvm

If you want a more detailed explanation about the regex, you can read more here: https://regex101.com/r/B128DE/1

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way to do it without having to use DOM or (God forbid) regex is to strip tags and explode on three new lines.
Strip tags will remove all HTML and leave blank spaces in it's place.

```
$html = '<table id="table-1">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 1}}</p></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><p>Sample text 1 goes here..</p></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-3">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><p>{{Phrase 2}}</p></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-4">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><p>Sample text 2 goes here..</p></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL , strip_tags($html));

// Optional output. But the trim is needed so some 
// kind of loop is needed to remove the extra spaces
For($i=1; $i<count($arr);){
     Echo trim($arr[$i]) . "<Br>\n";
     $i = $i+2;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/gPQZn

Comment: didn't get any results though

Comment: What do you mean by that? It works on the link I posted.

Comment: it is empty on the result

Comment: Oh.. I see. Sorry about that. Must have been because I indented the code on 3v4l instead of here. I find it easier to do there and copy paste here. Here is a working link https://3v4l.org/RPPMG